# How to share image to Path.com for iOS

Tags: ios, path, oauth-2.0, share, social-networking

I try the guide here: [Path Developers Docs](https://path.com/developers/docs#intro)

I can get access token from Path API.
But I can not send post photo request `"POST /1/moment/photo"`.

Does anyone can do it?

I used [gtw-oauth2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/) to get access token from Path API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the request format

```
POST /oauth2/access_token HTTP/1.1
Host: partner.path.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: <LENGTH>

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT&client_secret=SECRET&code=CODE
```

`Content-Length` line is not required, in getting permanent access token

`code=CODE` - was very confusing, and i see you can get temporary access token, but can't get permanent access token, in this line, capital `CODE` MUST BE REPLACED WITH TEMPORARY ACCESS TOKEN

don't change `grant_type=authorization_code` only

I think this will help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

POST /oauth2/access_token HTTP/1.1
Host: partner.path.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CLIENT&client_secret=SECRET&code=CODE

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's always better if you can provide a detailed description of your solution.